# $\Big [ \frac{p-1}{p}\Big ]_n$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, legendre-symbol

this is equivalent to solving $x^n\equiv-1\pmod p$ where $p$ is a prime number.
if $n=2$, the solution is iff $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$.(if $p=2$ then all numbers are residues.)
I'm unsure about the rest of the powers.
if $p=2$ then all numbers are residues(thus $1$ is too).
if $p=3$ then iff $n\equiv 1 \pmod 2$
if $p=4$ then iff $n\equiv 1 \pmod 2$
can any of you find a general solution or help?

Comment: You can easily show that for odd $n$'s, $p-1$ is a solution for the congruency. Thus, you can restrict the problem to even $n$'s.

Comment: @rtybase , would you mind helping me understand what is meant by the title of the question ? I didn't understand what the writing indicates...

Comment: @Spectre, the key for understanding is <<solving $x^n\equiv-1\pmod p$ where $p$ is a prime number>>. Obviously $n=2$ case is wrongly stated, as seen from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#q_=_%C2%B11_and_the_first_supplement) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares).

Comment: @rtybase not that... I didn't understand what the title meant...

Comment: The notation used is something I have never gone through (put it simple, I am a noob at this)

Comment: @Spectre it's the [power residue symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_residue_symbol). Sometimes used with [square brackets](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jmsj/1261153639) (also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#Gaussian_integers)). And to make things more confusing see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_reciprocity#Primes_%E2%89%A1_1_(mod_3)) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_reciprocity#Dirichlet).

Comment: @rtybase , thanks for the confusion... :D